# Flask app filter multiple columns of SQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask project that interacts with MySQL db through flask_mysqldb.

My goal is to create a search engine that will allow the users to filter the database with multiple filters that will filter the different columns of my database.

I succeeded to make it work with one filter that filters one column but now I want multiple filters.

Here is what my code looks like

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL, MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__)
        
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'xxx'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT player_id FROM actions")
    player_id = cur.fetchall()  
    return render_template('index.html', player_id = player_id)

@app.route("/fetchrecords",methods=["POST","GET"])
def fetchrecords():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['action']
        player_id = request.form['player_id']
        type = request.form['type']
        if query == '':
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM actions")
            datalist = cur.fetchall()
        else:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM actions WHERE type = (%s) AND player_id = (%s);", [type, player_id])
            datalist = cur.fetchall()  
    return jsonify({'htmlresponse': render_template('response.html', datalist=datalist)})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Filters</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br />
                <h2 align="center">Filters</h2><br />

                <select name="search_filter_player1" id="search_filter_player1" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Player 1</option>';
                {% for row in player_id %}
                    <option value="{{row.player_id}}">{{row.player_id}}</option>';    
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_value_player1" id="hidden_value_player1" />
                <div style="clear:both"></div>

                <select name="search_filter_type" id="search_filter_type" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Type</option>';
                        <option value="3FGA">3FGA</option>';  
                        <option value="3FGM">3FGM</option>';
                        <option value="2FGA">2FGA</option>';
                        <option value="2FGM">2FGM</option>';
                        <option value="FTA">FTA</option>';
                        <option value="FTM">FTM</option>';  
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_value_type" id="hidden_value_type" />
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>

            <br />
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Edition</th>
                            <th>Game</th>
                            <th>Player</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                load_data();
                function load_data()
                {
                    $('.load_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
                    var action = 'fetch_data';
                    var player_id = $('#hidden_value_player1').val();
                    var type = $('#hidden_value_type').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"/fetchrecords",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:{action:action, player_id:player_id, type:type},
                        success:function(data)
                        { 
                            $('.load_data').html(data);
                            $('.load_data').append(data.htmlresponse);
                        }
                    })
                }
             
                $('#search_filter').change(function(){
                    $('#hidden_value_player1').val($('#search_filter_player1').val());
                    $('#hidden_value_type').val($('#search_filter_type').val());
                    var player_id = $('#hidden_value_player1').val();
                    var type = $('#hidden_value_type').val();
                    load_data();
                });
                 
            });

            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**response.html**

```
{% for row in datalist %}  
<tr>
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.edition_id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.game_id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.player_id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.type}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Right now, my flask app doesn't return any data.

I think that there is something wrong with the script part of my index.html.
Is there a better way to do it sqlalchemy ?

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your JS code refers to an element with `class="load_data"` which neither HTML template includes. What Flask document or tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple things, not necessarily related:

- `type` is a built-in Python keyword, so using it for a variable can be problematic. I suggest you rename this.
- Your HTML form should be enclosed within `<form>` tags. This is malformed HTML, so it could work or not work depending on the level of tolerance of the browser. But the form needs the correct target attribute. I am not sure the form is even being submitted right now.
- I recommend that you test your form **without** Javascript first, and dump `request.form` to make sure you are receiving the expect output. When you confirm this is working, do the JS version.
- As far as I can tell the hidden fields are completely unnecessary. Just use the combo boxes.

Also, your browser (Firefox or other) likely has developer tools you should use to capture the requests being made, along with the server responses.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am very new at this so I am struggling a bit. I changed type to action and added <form> but nothing changed. For the rest of your recommendation, I don't know how to do it. How can I make sure that I am getting the output from my request.form ? Thanks in advance again